# The method parse_datetime from Perl's DateTime::Format::Strptime can't parse timezone name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, strptime

I have a laptop with ubuntu 12.04.
The execution of date command at the console result this:

```
$ date
Thu May  8 15:28:12 WIB 2014
```

The perl script below will be running well.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

$parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z");

$date = "Fri Sep 20 08:22:42 2013 WIB";
$dateimap = $parser->parse_datetime($date);
$date = $dateimap->strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %z");
print "$date\n";

$date = "Fri Jan  8 16:49:34 2010 WIT";
$dateimap = $parser->parse_datetime($date);
$date = $dateimap->strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S %z");
print "$date\n";
```

The result is

```
20-Sep-2013 08:22:42 +0700
08-Jan-2010 16:49:34 +0900
```

But, why the timezone name "WIT" is converted to timezone "+0900" ?
AFAIK, WIT is *Western Indonesian Time*. IMHO it should has timezone "+0700" not "+0900".

The other computer has a running CentOS 5.9.

The execution of date command at the CentOS result:

```
$ date
Thu May  8 15:38:24 WIT 2014
```

But the execution of the perl script above result like this:

```
20-Sep-2013 08:22:42 +0700
Can't call method "strftime" on an undefined value at strptime.pl line 14.
```

Actually the method parse_datetime can't parse the date which contain "WIT" timezone.
The returned value $dateimap is empty or undef.

The CentOS have been set to localtime Asia/Jakarta.

```
$ ls -l /etc/localtime 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Sep 23  2013 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Jakarta
```

Any suggestion ?

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indonesia - WIT is actually "Waktu Indonesia Timur" - Eastern Indonesian Time. So +9

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem happens because the version of module DateTime::Format::Strptime at CentOS 5.9 is 1.2000 while at ubuntu 12.04 is 1.54.

Another problem using the older version of DateTime::Format::Strptime.

```
$ perl -e '
> use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
> $parser   = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");
> $datembox = "Wed Jan  1 06:42:18 2014 WIT";
> $date = $parser->parse_datetime($datembox);
> print "$date\n";'

$
```

If we remove double spaces at variable $datembox.

```
$ perl -e '
> use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
> $parser   = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");
> $datembox = "Wed Jan  1 06:42:18 2014 WIT";
> $datembox =~ s/[\s]+/ /g;
> $date = $parser->parse_datetime($datembox);
> print "$date\n";'
2014-01-01T06:42:18
$
```